# ZBAR Scanner application crashes on Android 6.0 when trying to dynamically load library

Tags: java, android, sdk, loadlibrary, zbar

I am using ZBAR library to decode the QR Codes in my application. The application crashes when I am trying to dynamically download the library:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("iconv");
}
```

Here is my full code for this Activity:

```
public class ScanGoodActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    private static final String TAG = "ScanGoodActivity";
    private Camera mCamera;
    private CameraPreview mPreview;
    private Handler autoFocusHandler;

    private Button scanButton;
    private Button back;
    private Button done;
    private ImageScanner scanner;
    private int n = 0;
    private String s[];

    private boolean barcodeScanned = false;
    private boolean previewing = true;
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("iconv");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.scan_good_activity);
        s = new String[1000];
        initControls();
    }

    private void initControls() {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        autoFocusHandler = new Handler();
        //releaseCamera();
        mCamera = getCameraInstance();
        scanner = new ImageScanner();
        scanner.setConfig(0, Config.X_DENSITY, 3);
        scanner.setConfig(0, Config.Y_DENSITY, 3);

        mPreview = new CameraPreview(ScanGoodActivity.this, mCamera, previewCb,
                autoFocusCB);
        FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.cameraPreview);
        preview.addView(mPreview);

        scanButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scan_button);
        back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back_button);
        done = (Button) findViewById(R.id.done_button);

        scanButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (barcodeScanned) {
                    barcodeScanned = false;
                    mCamera.setPreviewCallback(previewCb);
                    mCamera.startPreview();
                    previewing = true;
                    mCamera.autoFocus(autoFocusCB);
                }
            }
        });
        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        done.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            releaseCamera();
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }


    public static Camera getCameraInstance() {
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            c = Camera.open(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return c;
    }

    private void releaseCamera() {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            previewing = false;
            mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }

    private Runnable doAutoFocus = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (previewing)
                mCamera.autoFocus(autoFocusCB);
        }
    };
    Camera.PreviewCallback previewCb = new Camera.PreviewCallback() {
        public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
            Camera.Size size = parameters.getPreviewSize();

            Image barcode = new Image(size.width, size.height, "Y800");
            barcode.setData(data);

            int result = scanner.scanImage(barcode);

            if (result != 0) {
                previewing = false;
                mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
                mCamera.stopPreview();
                SymbolSet syms = scanner.getResults();
                for (Symbol sym : syms) {

                    Log.i("<<<<<<Asset Code>>>>> ",
                            "<<<<Bar Code>>> " + sym.getData());
                    String scanResult = sym.getData().trim();
                    s[n++] = scanResult;
                    showAlertDialog(scanResult + n);
                    barcodeScanned = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    };

    // Mimic continuous auto-focusing
    Camera.AutoFocusCallback autoFocusCB = new Camera.AutoFocusCallback() {
        public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
            autoFocusHandler.postDelayed(doAutoFocus, 1000);
        }
    };


    private void showAlertDialog(String message) {

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                n--;
            }
        })

                .show();
    }


}
```

and here is the gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.sanzharaubakir.storeapp"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zbar:1.8.2'
}
```

I tried to use SDK version 22 however if I use this SDK version I will not be able to check and request MANIFEST permissions, so I want to know if it is possible to solve this problem for SDK version 23?